# How do I copy elements in a parallel array into a new parallel array with no duplicates in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, parallel-processing, parallel-arrays

Hi guys I'm having a problem getting the right output for an assignment. I am looking for a way to copy a set of elements from one parallel array (which contains a string--int) to the other with no duplicate value. For example:
I have these set of parallel arrays

This is the ORIGINAL PARALLEL ARRAY :

```
String[] phoneNumbers;           
    phoneNumbers = new String[100];
    int[] callDurations = new int[phoneNumbers.length];
    int size = 0;

    phoneNumbers[0] = "888-555-0000";
    callDurations[0] = 10;
    phoneNumbers[1] = "888-555-1234";
    callDurations[1] = 26;
    phoneNumbers[2] = "888-555-1234";
    callDurations[2] = 2;
    size = 3;
```

I want to create a method that creates new pairs of parallel arrays from the original arrays (phoneNumber & callDuration).This method would be called totalDuration and it would return no value(void). It would check if a number from the current array is in the new array, if yes, it will just add any duplicate duration to the current duration. if no, it would add a new element to the NewNumber array and add an element to the NewDuration array.

```
public static int find(String[] list, int size, int start, String target) {
    int pos = start;

    while (pos < size && !target.equals(list[pos])) {
        pos++;
    }

    if (pos == size)
        pos = -1;

    return pos;
}
```

This find method would be used to check if a phone number has already been placed in the new arrays, and if so, to determine where that number is.

For example, if the array contains

```
    phoneNumbers[0] = "888-555-0000";
    callDurations[0] = 10;
    phoneNumbers[1] = "888-555-1234";
    callDurations[1] = 26;
    phoneNumbers[2] = "888-555-1234";
    callDurations[2] = 2;
```

printing calls details for "888-555-1234" would look like:

```
    all calls from: 
Calls from 888-555-1234:
888-555-1234 duration: 26s
888-555-1234 duration: 2s
```

the output for the new method instead should be(26s +2s):

```
    all calls from: 
Calls from 888-555-1234:
888-555-1234 duration: 28s
```

I tried to solve it with this code but its giving a wrong output:

```
public static void totalDurations(String[] phoneNumbers, int[] callDuration, int size, String target) {
    String[] NewNumbers;
    int[] NewDuration;
    int pos;

    NewNumbers = new String[phoneNumbers.length];
    NewDuration = new int[callDuration.length];
    pos = find(phoneNumbers,size, 0,target);
    while(pos < size && !target.equals(phoneNumbers[pos])) {
        NewNumbers[pos] = phoneNumbers[pos];
        NewDuration[pos] = callDuration[pos];
        System.out.println(NewNumbers[pos] + "duration" + NewDuration[pos] +"s");
    }

}
```

NOT-RELATED
The code I use to get all my details for each call is my method "findAllCalls"

```
public static void findAllCalls(String[] phoneNumbers, int[] callDurations, int size, String targetNumber) {
    int matchPos;

    System.out.println("Calls from " + targetNumber + ":");
    matchPos = find(phoneNumbers, size, 0, targetNumber);
    while (matchPos >= 0) {
        System.out.println(phoneNumbers[matchPos] + " duration: " + callDurations[matchPos] + "s");


        matchPos = find(phoneNumbers, size, matchPos + 1, targetNumber);
    }
}

System.out.println("\n all calls from: ");
    findAllCalls(phoneNumbers,callDurations,size,"888-555-1234");
```

Any correction would be much appreciated in advance.

Comment: I havn't gone through your code but can you solve it using set ?

Comment: no, it has to be through a method

Comment: Rather than using an array, i would suggest using an array of class which has number, list of callDurations and total duration at last.  not much effort indeed. But you need to maintain a map for number string to its corresponding object

Comment: it can  be done through Hashmap also...i think it would be easier with that.

Comment: yes using maps would definitely make it easier. I wish I could use it, but I have to follow the instructions on the assignment. This is like the 5th and last method I'm creating

Comment: Java is an Object Oriented language. Emphasis on **Object**. Don't create parallel arrays, define a class, e.g. `Call`, with two fields, e.g. `phoneNumber` and `duration`, or a class like @SacJn suggested. --- If it's from an assignment, then whoever created that assignment needs to learn [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). --- Perhaps you could teach the teacher a lesson. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to your question the method for printing total duration of a target number can be like following

```
    public static int numberIndex(String[] numbers, String target) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if(numbers[i].equals(target)) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static void totalDuration(String[] phoneNumbers, int[] callDurations, String target) {
        String[] newNumbers = new String[phoneNumbers.length];
        int[] newDurations = new int[callDurations.length];
        int newIndex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++) {
            int oldIndex = numberIndex(newNumbers, phoneNumbers[i]);

            if(oldIndex == -1) {
                newNumbers[newIndex] = phoneNumbers[i];
                newDurations[newIndex] = callDurations[i];
                newIndex++;
            }
            else {
                newDurations[oldIndex] += callDurations[i];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < newIndex; i++) {
            System.out.println("Total duration for " + newNumbers[i] + ": " + newDurations[i]);
        }
    }
```

As you mentioned that the return type of this method should be `void`, so I assumed you only need to print the total duration. For that there is no need to construct new arrays like `NewNumbers` or `NewDurations`.

If holding them in arrays is absolutely necessary, let me know in the comment.

Comment: yes, holding them in this new array is absolutely necessary

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your code. It doesn't print out anything

Comment: It does print. Look at the last `for` loop in `totalDuration` method.